# SAS SQL Query - linking to SAS data set stored on UNIX folder

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I have a SAS dataset consisting of CUSTOMER IDS stored on my UNIX folder (TABLE NAME IS `CUSTOMERID`) . I need to get information about all these CUSTOMER IDS from CUSTOMER INFORMATION TABLE

I use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERINFORMATION
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN (select * from CUSTOMERID)
```

I get an error because the TABLE CUSTOMER ID is on UNIX while the QUERY is running on ORACLE (using SAS)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're running the SQL query in pass-through SQL.  In that case, you can't directly access SAS data.  You need to either construct the entire SQL query using `LIBNAME` access, or you need to upload your `CUSTOMERID` table to UNIX.

IE, if you have

```
proc sql;
connect to oracle (connection string);
select * from connection to oracle (
  select * from customerinformation where customerID in []
);
quit;
```

You could convert that to

```
libname ora oracle (connection string); *oracle or OLEDB or ODBC or etc.;
proc sql;
select * from ora.customerinformation where customerId in 
  (select * from unix.customerID);
quit;
libname ora clear;
```

Or you could load the table to Oracle, using the same libname method.

Finally, if the list of CustomerIDs is small enough, you could store it in a macro variable that contained a comma delimited list of IDs; macro text will resolve as long as it's not in single quotes.